# Ada Access to Unconstrained Type at Static Address

Tags: arrays, ada, memory-address

The following is illegal Ada:

```
type Byte_Array is array (Natural range <>) of Interfaces.Unsigned_8;
type Byte_Array_Access is access all Byte_Array;
bytes : aliased Byte_Array(0 .. 9999);
for bytes'Address use To_Address(16#0040_0000#);
bytes_Access : Byte_Array_Access := bytes'Access;
```

and the compiler produces the error:

```
object subtype must statically match designated subtype
```

on the last line. The workaround I have seen is to explicitly initialize the array like this:

```
bytes : aliased Byte_Array := (0 .. 9999 => 0);
```

However, this does not work for me as I have nonvolatile data stored at address `16#0040_0000#` that cannot be overwritten. What are my options?

---

**More info:**

I would like to add that you can avoid explicitly initializing the array via:

```
bytes : aliased Byte_Array := (0 .. 9999 => <>);
```

However, this still fails to compile, producing the different error:

```
aliased object "bytes" with unconstrained array nominal subtype
can overlay only aliased object with compatible subtype
```

on the line `for bytes'Address use To_Address(16#0040_0000#);` .

Comment: Perhaps an access type to `Interfaces.Unsigned_8` and `byte(0)'Access` would fit your needs?

Comment: Address_To_Access conversion on bytes'Address.

Comment: Your `bytes` is of an anonymous constrained subtype. Turn it into a named constrained subtype, then have your acess type point to the new subtype

Comment: @egilhh lel, true that xD Qualified expriession... Byte_Array_Access'(Bytes'Access) should do the trick...

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that a `Byte_Array_Access` is a fat pointer designating two things, the bounds of the actual array and the address of its first element.

Comment: Since access types are never needed in Ada*, why are you using them? (* 1st order approximation. Probably true to 2nd or 3rd order as well.)

Comment: I have downstream object oriented packages that manage regions of memory, ie. are provided Byte_Array_Access types at initialization. These packages can manage any size of byte array which is why I desire the fat pointer that @SimonWright mentioned. I need both the `'Length` and address of the array.

Comment: @darkestkhan Will `Address_to_Access_Conversion` will preserve the length of `bytes` in the `bytes_Access` fat pointer? It doesn't seem like that is possible. I also don't understand how the qualified expression helps. I tried that, but it still produces the same compilation error. Can you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: When you find yourself fighting the language, it is usually a sign that you have a design problem. A basic design rule for packages is that they should not require the use of access types by their clients. Since your "downstream packages" violate this rule, you have found your design problem. When you correct it, your difficulties will disappear.

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter Do you have a better idea for how I can have a package manage a specific region of memory without providing an access type (or address) from the client? The only alternative I can think of is to hard code the address and length inside the package itself which renders the package completely un-reusable, a much more severe design problem in my opinion.

Comment: Design proceeds from the problem statement, the reason you're creating S/W in the first place. "A pkg to manage a specific region of memory" is part of a specific design. I'm talking about returning to the problem statement and considering alternative designs. (I don't know what "manage a region of memory" means, but it and your posting seems to indicate that you're trying to do something low-level and probably platform and compiler dependent. Such code is rarely reusable.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would it help to make your own sort of 'accessor'? something like

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Interfaces;
with System;
with System.Address_Image;
procedure Byte_Arrays is
   type Byte_Array is array (Natural range <>) of Interfaces.Unsigned_8;
   package Access_Byte_Array is
      type Byte_Array_Access is private;
      function Form_Access (Of_Array : Byte_Array) return Byte_Array_Access;
      function Address (Of_Array : Byte_Array_Access) return System.Address;
      function Length (Of_Array : Byte_Array_Access) return Integer;
   private
      type Byte_Array_Access is record
         The_Array : System.Address;
         First : Natural;
         Last : Integer;  -- could have zero length
      end record;
      function Address (Of_Array : Byte_Array_Access) return System.Address
      is (Of_Array.The_Array);
      function Length (Of_Array : Byte_Array_Access) return Integer is
        (if Of_Array.Last < Of_Array.First
         then 0
         else Of_Array.Last - Of_Array.First + 1);
   end Access_Byte_Array;
   package body Access_Byte_Array is
      function Form_Access (Of_Array : Byte_Array) return Byte_Array_Access
      is
      begin
         return (The_Array => Of_Array'Address,
                 First => Of_Array'First,
                 Last => Of_Array'Last);
      end Form_Access;
   end Access_Byte_Array;
   use Access_Byte_Array;
   Bytes : aliased Byte_Array(0 .. -9999);
   for Bytes'Address use System'To_Address(16#0040_0000#);
   Bytes_Access : constant Byte_Array_Access := Form_Access (Bytes);
begin
   Put_Line (Length (Bytes_Access)'Image);
   Put_Line (System.Address_Image (Address (Bytes_Access)));
end Byte_Arrays;
```

with output

```
$ ./byte_arrays 
 10000
0000000000400000
```

---

[later] For FSF GNAT 10.1.0 on macOS, these changes work:

```
   type Standard_Access is access all Byte_Array;
...
      function Standard_Accessor
        (Of_Array : aliased Byte_Array_Access) return Standard_Access;
...

      type Bounds is record
         Lower : Integer;
         Upper : Integer;
      end record with Pack;
      type Byte_Array_Access is record
         The_Array  : System.Address;
         The_Bounds : Bounds;
      end record;
...
      function Standard_Accessor
        (Of_Array : aliased Byte_Array_Access) return Standard_Access
      is
         type Raw_Accessor is record
            Contents : System.Address;
            Bounds_P : System.Address;
         end record with Pack;
         function Convert
         is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Raw_Accessor, Standard_Access);
         Raw_Result : constant Raw_Accessor
           := (Contents => Of_Array.The_Array,
               Bounds_P => Of_Array.The_Bounds'Address);
      begin
         return Convert (Raw_Result);
      end Standard_Accessor;
```

`Standard_Accessor`’s parameter has to be aliased so that it’s passed by reference rather than on the stack. Of course, you have to be careful not to delete it while the `Standard_Access` is extant, so perhaps best always declared at package level.

Comment: This was where I was also heading. The issue I have with this is that I have many packages already written in terms of the `Byte_Array_Access` type I defined that use the `'Length` attribute. It would be annoying to have to convert all of this to use a `Length` function instead of an attribute. What you are doing seems to imitate the Ada compiler's dope used for unconstrained array accesses. I am now wondering if it might be better form for me to uncover how the dope works for my implementation and then create a `Form_Access` function that returns an actual fat `Byte_Array_Access` pointer.

Comment: That would be low level, and likely not portable, but at least the code would use standard Ada attributes instead of a custom rolled substitute like you presented.

Comment: I have some notes where I was working out how to do this, but danged if I can find the actual code! As you say, probably not portable between compilers (and possibly not even between  different releases of the same compiler).

Comment: Thank you for providing that macOS example, that is extremely helpful. I will have to contemplate the best direction to go with this, but I think I now have all the options in front of me. Thank you for your insight!